# Как лучше хранить данные в БД WordPress и выполнять экспорт/импорт в файл?

Tags: wordpress, база-данных

Как лучше хранить данные в БД WordPress и выполнять экспорт/импорт в файл?

есть input (форма) для ввода кода, который сверяется с одной таблицей , если код существует то он записывается в другую таблицу вместе с датой и другими фиксированными значениями с новой строки и слитно.

Также эти обе таблицы нужно делать экспорт/импорт в файл.
Использование этой формы может доходить более 200 раз в день.

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше это реализовать

В БД как лучше хранить?

1. зарегистрировать новый тип через register_post_type() и создавать новые посты для каждого кода ? или хранить это в виде массива в описании все в одном посте? или записать весь массив в метаданные к одному посту?
2. записывать весь массив в update_option() (с отключенным $autoload) . Здесь как и в предыдущем случае, я полагаю, придется сначала получить данные, а потом добавить новые и отправить (со временем если данных будет много, это возможно будет сжирать память)
3. создать свою таблицу через $wpdb ?

Как делать экспорт/импорт в файл ?

1. если делать запись в файл и его отправку через фтп при каждом запуске формы - то не потеряется часть данных, если одновременно несколько людей отправит эту форму?
2. как сделать экспорт/импорт в файл раз в день , если в БД таблица создана через $wpdb (то есть она отличается от стандарта WP ) обычно я использую wp all import , но как здесь поступать?
3. Также эта таблица может сильно разрастись с течением времени - как это возможно контролировать ? (к примеру удалять записи старше года)

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кастомный тип поста тут не нужен. Тем более, не надо это запихивать в опции. Для решения таких задач создают свою таблицу через $wpdb.

Файл надо выгружать асинхронно, по времени. Для этого в WP существует механизм cron. Тогда вы точно уверены, что запись файла идет из одного процесса.

Так же по времени раз в день через cron, надо делать экспорт/импорт.

Контроль таблицы - снова асинхронным cron раз в сутки или в неделю. Один запрос на удаление старых элементов и всё.